# Why is my pandas dataframe only showing results for one dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

I have two datasets in CSV format that I want to loop through and show results for in one pandas dataframe. Right now my results in df are only showing for the B dataset but if I try to print "data" it shows my two CSV datasets that I have below.

The test CSV datasets are:

| Date | fastMA | slowMA | Ticker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 5 | A |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 5 | A |
| 03/01/2021 | 4 | 5 | A |
| 04/01/2021 | 5 | 5 | A |
| 05/01/2021 | 6 | 5 | A |
| 06/01/2021 | 7 | 5 | A |
| 07/01/2021 | 4.5 | 5 | A |
| 08/01/2021 | 4 | 5 | A |
| 09/01/2021 | 3 | 5 | A |

| Date | fastMA | slowMA | Ticker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 5 | B |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 5 | B |
| 03/01/2021 | 4 | 5 | B |
| 04/01/2021 | 5 | 5 | B |
| 05/01/2021 | 6 | 5 | B |
| 06/01/2021 | 7 | 5 | B |
| 07/01/2021 | 4.5 | 5 | B |
| 08/01/2021 | 4 | 5 | B |
| 09/01/2021 | 3 | 5 | B |

```
ticker = csv.reader(open('gdrive/My Drive/data/test/test_tickers/test_tickers.csv'))
for symbols in ticker:

  tickers = symbols
  data = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/data/test/test_data/{}.csv'.format(symbols))

  i = 1
  j = len(data)
  in_trade = 0
  dates = []
  symbol = []

  while i < j:
    long = data["fastMA"][i] > data["slowMA"][i]
    close = data["fastMA"][i] < data["slowMA"][i] 

    if long and in_trade == 0:
      in_trade = 1
      symbol.append(data["Ticker"][i])
      dates.append(data["Date"][i])
      i += 1
    elif long and in_trade == 1:
      in_trade = 1
      i += 1
    elif close and in_trade == 1:
      in_trade = 0
      i += 1
    else:
      i += 1
d = {'Date':dates,'Ticker':symbol}
d
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=('Date','Ticker'))
df
```

Do I need to add in something else?

EDIT:

The output I'm getting now in df:

| Date | Ticker |
| --- | --- |
| 05/01/2021 | B |

My desired output in df:

| Date | Ticker |
| --- | --- |
| 05/01/2021 | A |
| 05/01/2021 | B |

Comment: Please show your desired output

Comment: Desired output added. Thank you.

Comment: I think my dates and symbol lists are clearing between each loop, so it is taking the results from dataset A and then clearing those and starting again for dataset B. Which is why only dataset B results are showing.

I need to hold the previous results.

Comment: be more systematic in your approach.  1. load / prepare data. 2. process / calculations on data. 3. reshape for desired output.   You are mixing all three together and making mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `ticker` row that is read in, you were blanking `dates` and `symbol`, they need to be outside of your loop. If you restructure a bit, you should get your desired output:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('test_tickers.csv', newline='') as f_tickers:    
    csv_tickers = csv.reader(f_tickers)
    dates = []
    symbols = []

    for symbol in csv_tickers:
        data = pd.read_csv(f'{symbol[0]}.csv')

        i = 1
        j = len(data)
        in_trade = 0

        while i < j:
            long = data["fastMA"][i] > data["slowMA"][i]
            close = data["fastMA"][i] < data["slowMA"][i] 

            if long and in_trade == 0:
                in_trade = 1
                symbols.append(data["Ticker"][i])
                dates.append(data["Date"][i])
            elif long and in_trade == 1:
                in_trade = 1
            elif close and in_trade == 1:
              in_trade = 0
            
            i += 1

d = {'Date' : dates, 'Ticker' : symbols}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=('Date','Ticker'))

print(df)
```

Giving:

```
         Date Ticker
0  05/01/2021      A
1  05/01/2021      B
```

(This assumes `test_tickers.csv` contains two lines containing `A` and `B` and the `A.csv` and `B.csv` contains the data in your question)